# Make button inactive when LocalStorage is empty

Tags: javascript, css

I have this cobbled together setup which displays words in a list. Users can click a heart next to store the word in localStorage. When the first word is added, the red button at the top of the page (which will contain a link to the favourites page) becomes active.

This has the working code (I couldn't do a snippet on SO as I don't think localStorage is supported, or my code to get it to work isn't anyway):

https://codepen.io/20201015/pen/LYZGKNv

### HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="container" style="margin:20px;">

  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="success" href="#" disabled="disabled" style="pointer-events: none;"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> View</a>

  <div class="scrollbox list" style="background:#000;">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li id="fairunmuzzled">fairunmuzzled</li>
    <li id="illusionpat">illusionpat</li>
    <li id="impureblossom">impureblossom</li>
    <li id="arousedsolemn">arousedsolemn</li>
    <li id="bamboopeeves">bamboopeeves</li>
    <li id="mudrubbish">mudrubbish</li>
    <li id="rickshawobject">rickshawobject</li>
  </ul>
  </div>

<a href="#" onclick="localStorage.removeItem('jpxun');" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Delete Local Storage</a>

<p>If delete all, refresh page to see that the red button is inactive again.</p>
   
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
var ct = 0;
var jpxun = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jpxun')) || [];

// check if usernames local storage item is already populated

var MyUsernames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jpxun'));

// if it is, make the red button active

if (MyUsernames) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('success');
    if (elem) {
        elem.removeAttribute('disabled');
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
    }
}

// count elements
if (jpxun) { // count elements
    for (var i = 0; i < jpxun.length; i++) {
        ct ++;
    }
} else {
    ct = 0;
}

var lists = document.querySelectorAll('.list');

if (lists.length) {
  lists.forEach(list => {
    list.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if (!e.target.id) return;
      var id = e.target.id;
      var item = e.target;
      var temp = ct++;
      var newCt = "" + temp + ""; // need to wrap ID in speech marks to get delete element functionality to work
      var findme = jpxun.findIndex(e => e.name == id);
      
      // add word to localStorage
      
      if (findme == -1) {
        jpxun.push({ id: newCt, name: id });
        item.className = 'fav';
        var elem = document.getElementById('success');
        elem.removeAttribute('disabled');
        elem.removeAttribute('style');
        
      // remove word from localStorage
        
      } else {
        jpxun.splice(findme, 1)
        item.className = 'nofav';
      }
      localStorage.setItem('jpxun', JSON.stringify(jpxun));
    });
  });
}
```

It does work okay (please pardon all of the glaring errors, omissions, bad practices etc. etc.).

What I'd like to do is work out how, on this bit of the JS, to disable the red button if the localStorage is empty:

```
      // remove word from localStorage
        
      } else {
        jpxun.splice(findme, 1)
        item.className = 'nofav';
      }
```

I realise the bit to remove a word from localStorage needs to be changed to:

1. Count the number of elements left when a word is deleted
2. If there are no items left then delete the whole localStorage via `localStorage.removeItem('jpxun');` and change the CSS on the red button to make it inactive.

I have tried various things to get that to work, but couldn't come up with an elegant solution, so I thought I'd ask people here for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay so you have three requests :

1 -  to disable the red button if the localStorage is empty that easy just check if there is local storage if not set disabled to true like this snippet

```js
// NOTE for the demo here i will create a localstorage object to make the code work but for you just remove the line
const localStorage = { getItem : () =>  false }
 ///////////////////////////////////////////


let buttonEnabled = false

if (localStorage.getItem("jpxun")) {
// here we set the var to true
    buttonEnabled = true
}

// here we set the button disabled attribute to buttonEnabled

document.getElementById('fav').setAttribute("disabled" , buttonEnabled)
```

```html
<button id="fav">PRESS ME ! </button>
```

2 -  Count the number of elements left when a word is deleted if I understand correctly for this one just get the length after you splice

```
let numberOfElements = jpxun.length
else {
        jpxun.splice(findme, 1)
        numberOfElements = jpxun.length
        item.className = 'nofav';
      }
```

3 - If there are no items left then delete the whole localStorage via localStorage.removeItem('jpxun'); and change the CSS on the red button to make it inactive.

i think the first answer is similar just in the main function recheck now If you have any item left by getting them and checking the length if lenght = 0 then

```
 localStorage.removeItem('jpxun');
```

Comment: Instead of removing the item from the storage you can just check if anything is inside the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the data in the `localStorage` named `jpxun`. You can check if it's undefined. If it's not undefined, you can check if there is anything inside the JSON in it.

That's how I'd implement it:

```
if(typeof localStorage.jpxun == "undefined" || 
Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('jpxun'))).length<1){
    // ...
}
```

Comment: CleverSkull, mind you explaining your answer please and give some context?

Comment: You are storing the data in the localStorage named jpxun. So you can check if it's undefined. If it's not undefined you can check if there is anything inside the JSON in it.